# WinForms becomes irresponsive, async programming, C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have one problem. When I don't use await keyword in my async method, after I press the button, winform becomes irresponsive for a few seconds and then the textbox is filled with the corresponsing data (then winform becomes responsive), but when I use await keyword, after pressing button click WinForms becomes and stays irresponsive forever. What is my mistake?

This is **with await** keyword:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        textBox1.Text = AccessTheWebAsync().Result.ToString();
}

async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        Task<string> GetString = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
        string urlContents = await GetString;

      
        return urlContents.Length;
}
```

This is **without await** keyword:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        textBox1.Text = AccessTheWebAsync().Result.ToString();
}

async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string urlContents = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com").Result.ToString();

        return urlContents.Length;
}
```

Comment: It is a classic deadlock. Do not block on async with `.Result`.

Comment: As far as I can see it should be var x  = await  client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably have a deadlock.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        textBox1.Text = AccessTheWebAsync().Result.ToString();
}
```

should be:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var length = await AccessTheWebAsync();
    textBox1.Text = length.ToString();
}
```

If you ever find yourself accessing `.Result`, you're probably doing it wrong. In your event handler, mark it as `async void` (only appropriate for the Main method or event handlers) and await the result of your async call. Pay very careful attention to [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) because async code is tricky.

Accessing `.Result` can result in deadlocks, which would explain why it became unresponsive for you.

Comment: Is it safe (or even possible in this case) to use `async void`? I think the poster should just use `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @xxbbcc If you read the article I linked to in my answer, it says to avoid `async void` with the exception of event handlers. It's in the table at the top. There's also some discussion in the main article about why it's okay there.

Comment: @xxbbcc yes `async void` is fine for a event handler since they don't return anything but not for others though. Moreover, with `async/await` in hand why you want to use `BackgroundWorker` at all ... that's stoneage

Comment: @Rahul / mason Ok, thank you. I did read the article (long ago) but I wasn't ever quite sure how this bit worked.